# AWS VPC Peering connection - measuring traffic

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-vpc-peering

How can I measure the traffic that is going via a VPC Peering connection?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [AWS VPC Flow Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs.html)

According to the documentation:

> VPC Flow Logs is a feature that enables you to capture information
> about the IP traffic going to and from network interfaces in your VPC.

You can push this data to S3, cloud watch, Kinesis etc and then perform your required metrics.

Comment: Flow logs is an option, but comes with some challenges as far as I can see. First one is I can't see how to capture flow logs for the peering connection alone, is that possible? If not then how to filter to peering connection traffic only? dstaddr seems only option for that - flow log fields
${version} ${account-id} ${interface-id} ${srcaddr} ${dstaddr} ${srcport} ${dstport} ${protocol} ${packets} ${bytes} ${start} ${end} ${action} ${log-status}